# How to make width of inner element 100 perecent with position absolute in node?

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<span class="ui-btn-inner">
    <span class="ui-btn-text">TEST
        <span class="title">
            Name<br>Professional
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-btn-text .title {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 70%;
}
.ui-btn-inner .ui-btn-text .title {
    display: none;
    font-size: 0.77em;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
}
```

Here `ui-btn-inner` class node have full width of window(assume 1000px width for this node). The inner node `ui-btn-text` and `title` doesn't have relative width of parent node.

The `title` node have only width of `ui-btn-text` node content 'TEST', where an CSS property with `width: 70%;` is added to make width relative to parent node.

If I drop `position: absolute` from `title`, it will work correct. But I can't drop that property because mobile(iphone) integration needs it. How to make it correct?

Comment: `width = 100%` and `position: absolute` are mutually exclusive, sorry. I think you might need Javascript for this.

Comment: Why `display: none` ?? Full width method: did you try relative on a parent and `position:absolute;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0` ?

Comment: @FelipeAls Already the parent is relative.

Comment: And does the absolutely positioned element have `left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0`? That's the trick

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have `width:100%` on an element that is absolutely positioned.

> For absolutely positioned elements whose containing block is based on
>   a block container element, the percentage is calculated with respect
>   to the width of the padding box of that element. This is a change from
>   CSS1, where the percentage width was always calculated with respect to
>   the content box of the parent element.

Reference : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-percentage

Answer (score 0):

Don't use span, please use div.

The solution to give `width:100%;` on absolute element is to change your `position:absolute;` with `position:relative;`.  It will work if you only use `top:21px;` and `left:0;` positioning.

Comment: I already tried with relative. After rendering the element loses it's position.